# Format UTC Date Time

Tags: java, scala, date-formatting

On my machine, when I call `Instant.now` I get the following:

```
scala> import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> Instant.now
res1: java.time.Instant = 2017-03-03T07:05:41.192Z
```

It returns the fractional part of the second to the thousandths i.e. .192Z. I would like to only return it to the hundreths, so in this case .19Z. How can I do that?

I tried using `DateFormatter` but it blows up with the I put the `T` in the pattern string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter` with your custom pattern.

Sample:

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .format(Instant.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssZ";
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
```

Output:

```
2019-04-03T13:23:03.03+0530
2019-04-03T13:23:03.03+0530
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call:

`Instant.now().getMillis()`, 
this should return 192 as a Long